# How to rename a file in python 3 with translation table and what error am I making here

Tags: python, translation

I am trying to rename the files name by removing all the numbers from the file.

I am using python 3. So I need to do it through Translation table.

```
import os, string

def main ():
       #1 we need to take the files out from the folder
file_list = os.listdir("/Users/mirzasamibaig/Documents/prank")
#print(file_list)
saved_path = os.getcwd()
print("Current Working Directory is " + saved_path)
os.chdir("/Users/mirzasamibaig/Documents/prank")
rename_files(file_list)
def rename_files():

for file_name in file_list:
     translation_table = str.maketrans("0123456789", "", "0123456789")
     filename.translate(translation_table)
     os.chdir(saved_path)

     print (str.translate(file_list))

     if __name__ == "__main__":
         main()
```

here is the updated one, now help what I can do.

Comment: Never post image of code. Copy and paste in the question body itself please.

Comment: Your `file_list` is defined in the `rename_files` function yet you are trying to use it within `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling "rename_files" outside the main code. It should be called inside the loop.

Comment: True, but not relevant to the error in the question.

Comment: But it does not solve the problem. the guy to whom I am following he is doing just like that so I did

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of your rename_files function to main(). Then put the call to rename_files in the main() but pass a parameter called file_list i.e. rename_files(file_list). Then make a new function called rename_file(file_list).
Like this:

```
import os, string

def main():
       #1 we need to take the files out from the folder
    file_list = os.listdir("/Users/mirzasamibaig/Documents/prank")
    #print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("Current Working Directory is " + saved_path)
    os.chdir("/Users/mirzasamibaig/Documents/prank")

    rename_files(file_list, saved_path)

def rename_files(file_list, saved_path):

    for file_name in file_list:
         translation_table = str.maketrans("0123456789", "", "0123456789")
         filename.translate(translation_table)
         os.chdir(saved_path)

         print (str.translate(file_list))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: whats gonna happen if I do that.

Comment: Well hopefully it should work. Make a copy and try on that. Essentially the way you have it now is that file_list is local to rename_files() as it is set inside the function. So the other code you have written cannot see it i.e. for files_in file_list.

Comment: You will actually need to pass saved_path parameter as well i.e. rename_files(file_list, saved_path)

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: I've edited my answer to what it should look like

Comment: I am getting an error from the code but I couldn't able to write here.

Comment: put file_name.translate not filename.translate

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mirzasamibaig/Documents/secretmessage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mirzasamibaig/Documents/secretmessage.py", line 11, in main
    rename_files(file_list, saved_path)
  File "/Users/mirzasamibaig/Documents/secretmessage.py", line 20, in rename_files
    print (str.translate(file_list))
TypeError: descriptor 'translate' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'

Comment: Im not to familiar with translate but i'm guessing you should put print str.translate(filename). At present you are trying to print the list